# uncaught(in promise)typeError: when pass value to async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, sapper

I having error when pass value into data object, inside async function, here the code:

```
$:var1; //get value from form
$:var2; //get value from form
$:dataobject = {
    aa:"",
    bb:""
};
let examplefunction = async () => {
    dataobject["aa"]=var1;
    dataobject.bb=var2;
    if (dataobject["aa"].trim() === ""|| dataobject.bb.trim() === ""){
        return; //if no value in form, not proses anything.
    }
    // this function make connection to serverside API.
};
```

i do manage to pass the function, but when i did, i got error pointed to :

`if (dataobject["aa"].trim()....`

the error is, **EDITED**

> page_login.svelte:129 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dataobject.aa.trim is not a function

i also try to pass value using argument, but error persisted.

`let examplefunction = async (var1,var2 => {`

Comment: You might try `dataobject["aa"]=var1 || "";`. It sounds like the value being assigned from var1 might be null/undefined.

Comment: sorry that was mistake in my part.. i mean, the error was like this
`page_login.svelte:129 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dataobject.aa.trim is not a function`

Comment: Yeah, I got that. `trim` is part of `String.prototype` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)). If var1 isn't a string, that's the message you'll get.

Comment: i see. that actually solve my problem.. thank you

Comment: Not related to you question, but in your form you should use `<input bind:value={var1}>` so you don't have to use the `$:` syntax at all.